# RedBean crash if field begin with number

Tags: redbean

I have a table called User with a field called 10kssc of type integer

If I do this on an existing bean

```
echo $user->10kssc;
```

The code died with just an empty  tab

I can see this is in the docs for version 3 which doesnt suggest a field name cant start with a number

```
http://redbeanphp.com/manual3_0/schema
```

I cant find anything in the docs for v4

```
http://redbeanphp.com/welcome
```

In the mysql manual it says 'Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.'

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html
```

Naturally i can change the field name but you only progress by  understanding your 'mistakes'

Any help in advance is much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you can not access object property if it starts with numbers (is not legal variable). You can use [curly bracket syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) (section *Complex (curly) syntax*) as workaround in order to escape property name. In you your case it would be:

```
$user->{'10kssc'}
```